# Why is my PHP variable not changing when my Javascript code runs?

Tags: php, javascript

I have a counter timer and I tried to block a simple bypass to download without waiting.

so in main class I declared the boolean

```
$allow_download = false;
```

and in **Javascript** when the time is elapsed

```
else 
{
    textDLShow.style.display = 'none';
    divDLShow.style.display = '';
    "<?php $allow_download = true;?>";
}
```

and in the second class

```
if($allow_download == false)
echo "Test";
```

well, when time is elapsed the boolean is not set with positive value. Any suggestions ??

Thanks for your time !!

Comment: Client != Server

Comment: Javascript runs in the browser. PHP runs on the server before the html is sent to the browser. You are missing a key point about client vs server code.

Comment: @Adrian: PHP runs on the server, which generates output for the client. Javascript runs on the client, after the PHP has already executed.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. Do you can make a favor to suggest me another way to do this ? Thanks again.

Comment: No... look... please start from the basics. Learn the difference between server side code and client side code. You really, really have to do many "hello world"s before trying to do some actual work.

Comment: I made it in another way. I worked several years in java (for a game). So it's easy to make 'THINGS' but I don't know more things between PHP and JAVASCRIPT Anyway thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript cannot set the value of a PHP variable since the JavaScript interpreter cannot parse PHP (nor is the variable in the same interpreter anyway, since the JavaScript is run on the client's browser rather than on the server.)

In order to do this you will need to make a new request with JavaScript that your PHP code can read in order to set `$allow_download` to true and then serve up the download.

You'll want to read up on [`ajax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/ajax), [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement) (because one way to do this might be to create an iframe pointing at the download location after the time has elapsed) and [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout).

Answer (score 0):

PHP is run on your server, the variables you create are no longer in scope when your client side javascript runs. There is no way to fix this unless you want to cook up some heavier stuff like storing in a database which IP addresses can download which files at what time.

Comment: Bad idea. Use $_SESSION to identify users.

Answer (score 0):

php can run javascript, but javascript can never run php, take it for granted
the best thing you can do is run an ajax script to kind of call the php on the background
but really why bother going with all that, you can include the javascript in a php function and let it do the job

Comment: "php can run javascript" is entirely a true statement.  PHP can write javascript, which can be executed by the browser when it is loaded.